# Ordered and Unordered List is not rendered during the PDF Generation

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, html-parsing, html-lists, itext

I am using iText-5.5.6 and XMLWorker-5.5.6. I am having strange issue during the PDF Generation where as I am not able to see the Ordered or Unordered list from the source HTML Content.  I am getting the HTML Content from the Editor Control.  And the content is like the below:

```
       htmlContentEn = "<html><body style=\"font-family: Arial;\"><p>I personally thank you for your continued commitment and I look forward to continue our journey to make one of the best the world.</p><p>Bullets:</p><ol><li><div>One</div></li><li><div>Two</div></li><li><‌​div>Three</div></li></ol></body></html>";
```

**And the Java code below used to generate the PDF is below:**

```
 p = new XMLParser(worker); 
 p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContentEn.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 

 try{ 
   for (Element e : elements) { 
     contentEnCell.addElement(e); 
   }
 }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){ }
```

I need your help in  regard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this:

```
<html>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
<p>I personally thank you for your continued commitment and I look forward to continue
our journey to make one of the best the world.</p>
<p>Bullets:</p>
<ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

And it works correctly.

I've tried this:

```
<html>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
<p>I personally thank you for your continued commitment and I look forward to continue
our journey to make one of the best the world.</p>
<p>Bullets:</p>
<ol>
<li><div>One</div></li>
<li><div>Two</div></li>
<li><div>Three</div></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

And it doesn't work correctly.

While it's awkward to nest a `<div>` straight into an `<li>`, I'll report this in our issue tracker.

You can work around this problem by removing the unnecessary `<div>` tags (this will solve your problem immediately), or you'll have to wait for support at iText to fix this. If you are a customer, you'll get a hotfix. If you are not a customer, you'll have to wait a couple of months (we've just released 5.5.6). Note that using 5.5.6 may require that you're a customer: watch the video [Is iText free?](https://youtu.be/QHF3xcWnSD4) for more info.

Comment: Again useful help and quick response. I am doing this as an exercise for a Proof of Concept.

Comment: If you could prevent the HTML editor to add `<div>` tags inside the `<li>` tags, you'll be able to create the PDFs you need.

Comment: From your response, I am able to generate PDF. Thanks.